# How to get all posts belongs to a user between a certain date

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, users

I am writing a plugin for my company so I need to get all posts belongs to a user between a certain date which is given by another user.

Then I want to count words for each post and finally add them up to a variable and save that value to the database.

There are two main questions:

1- How to get all posts belongs to a user between a certain date?

2- How to get word count for each post?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [WP_Query reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

[For parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

[Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'author' => 123 ,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For the word count check out this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/total-word-count-for-posts-by-one-author). It has a quick way of doing it by using explode get the post content and then using explode and count.